# Why can't load chunk?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm writing an SPA application using vue and webpack. Now I'm trying to do lazy loading and code splitting for optimizing webpack bundle size.

And I load routes like this:
`const Route = () => import('../components/***/****')`

And I'm getting an error when I try to change url:

`Loading chunk 30 failed.
 at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete`

What I'm doing wrong? And how can I solve the issue?

Comment: Please include enough information to help us help you. How are you attempting to use this `Route` function? Are you sure the path to your component is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your router like this

```
import Router from 'vue-router' 

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [ 
    {
      path: '/my/specific/route',
      name: 'mySpecificroute',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "SpecificRoute" */ './components/****/****')
    }, 
  ]
})
```